# Chrome seems to be blocking amp-facebook, even on the official AMP website

Tags: amp-html

I built a clients entire website with AMP and it was working great, then suddenly two days ago amp-facebook stopped working entirely.

I checked the AMP by example page to see what I was doing wrong, and get this, none of the embeds are working there either.

https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-facebook/

I hope someone sees this soon!

Comment: can you post the errors you see in the dev console if any? I just checked and it works fine for me. Thanks

Comment: here's the errors from the amp playground


           ----------- f.js:1 -> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
           ----------- frame.html:9 -> Uncaught ReferenceError: draw3p is not defined

Comment: I would imagine that this would be a more widespread issue if this were true but I haven't seen anything related to this. You can reproduce this on your browser and the client's browser? Can you check if you have any chrome extensions that might be causing this to not work correctly. Thanks

Comment: you're absolutely right, its adblocker

but it's strange to me because a normal facebook embed works fine with adblocker. I'd even accept a message as a fallback when its enabled. but having it just go blank is a deal breaker for my client when the non amp embed is an option

Comment: Is this the ad blocker that you are speaking of. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ad-blocker/kacljcbejojnapnmiifgckbafkojcncf?hl=en-US. I installed it and the https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-facebook/ example is working fine. Do you have a test page that I can look at? Thanks

Comment: this is the one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bloc/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb. and here's my site https://aquadentalwellness.com/